# How to get character from string?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get separate character from a string which i am getting from an array.

```
string sChar=array[0].ToString();
```

Now if string at `array[0].ToString()` is "234"

```
int iChar = sChar[0];
```

now for position it should return me "2" but it returns "48". What i am missing ?

Comment: Does `char iChar = sChar[0];` do what you want?

Comment: are you trying to get an integer or a character? you say you're trying to separate characters, but you're using an int datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Use `int iChar = Convert.ToInt32(sChar.substring(0,1));`

Answer (score 0):

You are implicitly casting character (`byte`) to `int`.

Character `2` has a value of `50`.

Character `0` has a value of `48`.

So you should use `Convert.ToInt32()` or `int.TryParse()` method to convert character to equivalent integer

Answer (score 0):

Problem is during conversion of your `char` to `int`.
Try this:-

```
string[] sarray = { "234", "125", "842" };
string strElement = sarray[0];
int iChar = (int) Char.GetNumericValue(strElement[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
int first = Int16.Parse(arr[0][0].ToString());
```

What you're currently doing is only getting the index of the string from your string array, to access the character index, you must do another indexer.